# Pandas: Merging two rows (based on an ID) with potentially null values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe (df1) as follows:

```
     emg     prv      name
0    NDJ  prv_NS  beta_123
1    NDJ  prv_NS       NaN
2    NDJ  prv_NS      beta
3    HCO  prv_NS  alpha123
4    HCO  prv_NS       NaN
5  H135Y  prv_NS       NaN
6   TOY1  prv_NS  alpha_12
```

I would like to combine all the names for the same `emg`. So the output should look like:

```
     emg     prv            name
0    NDJ  prv_NS   beta_123/beta
3    HCO  prv_NS        alpha123
5  H135Y  prv_NS             NaN
6   TOY1  prv_NS        alpha_12
```

If there is no name for any of the EMG, I would just keep NaN and if there is, just concatenate the rows together.

---

My attempt at the solution was to use groupby and unique as follows:
`df1.groupby('emg').name.apply(lambda x: '/'.join(set(x.str))).reset_index`

But I seem to get an error saying: `df1.groupby('emg').name.apply(lambda x: '/'.join(set(x.str))).reset_index`

Is there a better way to what I'm doing?

Comment: Hi, here is some arguably unreadable answer `df.drop_duplicates("emg").assign(name=lambda fr: fr.emg.map(df.dropna(subset=["name"]).groupby("emg").name.agg("/".join)))`... I think you should go for the apply-based solution for readability. So I won't attempt to explain this line of code :) But it's no magic of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider two different cases: when a group has only NaNs and when it has at least one non-NaN name:

```
df.groupby('emg').name.apply(lambda x: 
    '/'.join(x.dropna().unique()) # at least one non-NaN <---\
    if x.notna().any() # the condition check ---->-----------|
    else np.nan # only NaN's <-------------------------------/
).reset_index()
#     emg           name
#0  H135Y            NaN
#1    HCO       alpha123
#2    NDJ  beta_123/beta
#3   TOY1       alpha_12
```

Comment: They say `apply` is slow but I think it's faster to read than apply-less `df.drop_duplicates("emg").assign(name=lambda fr: fr.emg.map(df.dropna(subset=["name"]).groupby("emg").name.agg("/".join)))` :) You didn't account for the column `"prv"` but +1.

Comment: @Neither While, in general, `apply` is slow, in this very specific example my solution is faster.

Comment: Oh, I see. How many rows the data had? How many distinct groups it had in the `emg` column? The NaN ratio? Or did you only test it on the 7 rows of data provided? Maybe those affect.

Comment: @DYZ the thing is this seems to be dropping the column 'prv', so is it possible to include it or would I have to do another merge with my original dataframe?

Comment: You never explained how to handle that column, and did not use it in your attempted solution. What happens if there are different values in that column for the merged rows?

Comment: @DYZ, thanks for the feedback. The 'prv' column will never be different. So if you look at the example, the emg of `NDJ` will have a `prv` of `prv_ns` all the time, there won't be differences or even any blank entries.